# snapd udevmon.go:184: udev monitor observed remove event for unknown device

Tags: php, snap, udev, syslog

I'm seeing these messages in the syslog on 18.10. How can I fix this? I've searched around and not found any solutions.
The two entries that occur approx. every hour in syslog are:

```
snapd[1893]: udevmon.go:184: udev monitor observed remove event for unknown device "/sys/dentry(3271:phpsessionclean.service)"

snapd[1893]: udevmon.go:184: udev monitor observed remove event for unknown device "/sys/proc_inode_cache(3279:phpsessionclean.service)"
```

Output:

```
$ dpkg -S phpsessionclean.service
php-common: /lib/systemd/system/phpsessionclean.service
```

Output:

```
$ dpkg -S udevmon.go
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *udevmon.go*
```

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue with a great many of the same and nearly identical entries many times per day.

Comment: Search on [packages.ubuntu.com for *udevmon.go*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=cosmic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=udevmon.go) gives package name - `golang-github-snapcore-snapd-dev`; and the *phpsessionclean.service* is from [`php-common` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=cosmic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=phpsessionclean.service&searchon=contents). Please add output of `dpkg -S udevmon.go` and `dpkg -S phpsessionclean.service` to the question. Both components are related to these messages.

Comment: @N0rbert I have the exact same output.

Comment: Possibly related: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/cleanup-before-services-go-down/5802

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a debug message which you can just ignore https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/log-snapd-and-btrfs-message/9809